# how to toggle the display of a div when click at all element in a div except a hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, plotly-dash

I am using the javascript below to toggle the display of ".detail" whenever i clicked the ".summary" div.  i wish to introduce a link in the ".summary" div but i don't want to toggle the ".detail" div when i click on the link.  how should i fix the code?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click",".summary",function(){
        $(this).next(".detail").toggleClass("show")
    })
});
```

PREV:

```
html.Div([
    html.Div([html.H5(corner, style={'paddingLeft':'25px', 'color':'#fff'})], className='three columns summary'),
    html.Div([html.H5(int_status, style={'paddingLeft':'25px', 'color':'#fff'})], className='three columns'),
    html.Div([html.H5(ext_status, style={'paddingLeft':'25px', 'color':'#fff'})], className='three columns'),
], className='row summary'),

html.Div([
    html.Div([dcc.Graph(id=f'binning-{corner}', figure=create_timing_graphs(partition, corner), 
        config={'displayModeBar':False})], 
        style={'paddingLeft':'40px'})
], style={**card_colors['default']}, className='row detail'),
```

NEW:

```
html.Div([
    html.Div([html.H5(corner, style={'paddingLeft':'25px', 'color':'#fff'})], className='three columns summary'),
    html.Div([html.H5(int_status, style={'paddingLeft':'25px', 'color':'#fff'})], className='three columns'),
    html.Div([html.H5(ext_status, style={'paddingLeft':'25px', 'color':'#fff'})], className='three columns'),
    html.Div(html.A(children='\u2630', style={'paddingLeft':'60px', 'color':'#fff'}, href=f'http://10.38.234.26:5000/{partition}_timing_summary.xlsx'), style={'marginTop':'5px'}, className='one column offset-by-two')
], className='row'),

html.Div([
    html.Div([dcc.Graph(id=f'binning-{corner}', figure=create_timing_graphs(partition, corner), 
        config={'displayModeBar':False})], 
        style={'paddingLeft':'40px'})
], style={**card_colors['default']}, className='row detail'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the target element

```
$(document).on('click', '.summary', function(e){
  var target = e.target;

  if(target.tagName !== 'A'){
    $(this).next('.detail').toggleClass('show');
  }
});
```

Comment: it works but the alert will pop up a window.  how can i disable the pop up?

Comment: updated the example to only toggle if the target element is not an anchor (link)

Comment: glad I could help :)